# How to get client's Proxy IP address in CometD?

Tags: java, proxy, ip, jetty, cometd

Using fiddler as a HTTP proxy, i connect to a local CometD server.

I inherit the class `DefaultSecurityPolicy`, and got the client's IP address with `server.getContext().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress()` in `canHandshake` Method.

However, it returns the client's real IP (original IP), but what i want is the one directly communicates with the server. Any help?

---

If the client using WebSocket to communicate with CometD server, The HTTP proxy doesn't take effect at all, So what i got is the original addr, am i right?

Comment: OK, i got the reason finally. Fiddler is just a http proxy, but i was using WebSocket... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getlocationFromIp()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { 
        // Check if using Shared Internet Environment 
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; 
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){ 
        // Check if using Proxy User 
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; 
    }else{ 
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    } 
    $ip_geo_url   = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$ipAddress;
    $ip_json    = file_get_contents($ip_geo_url);
    $ip_json    = json_decode($ip_json);
    return $ip_json;
}
```

it will get the location whit ip if it help you ... 
it will be get the proxy location too